# Feedback sensation and noise at gear shifter when pressing brake pedal

Tags: brakes, volvo, gear-stick, s80

I was about to turn out my carport this afternoon and experienced this sensation at my hand on the shifter when I pressed the brake. It was quiet too and I heard like some kind of noise like a hydraulic fluid pressurizing and depressurizing or clicking or something. I also felt a small tremble at the shifter. How are these systems connected exactly? Seems like something is surprisingly coupled here in this automatic transmission Volvo S80.

Actually there's some kind of interlock right whereby you can't change gears out of park unless you engage the brake? The shifter is locked somehow in park. What's this stuff called?